# Need to open context menu in widget onClick event

Tags: android, android-widget, android-contextmenu

I have created a `widget` in my application , now *when a widget is clicked I want to show few options in a* `context menu` and allow the user to choose one of them.

My widget contains icon and text , so when a user click over an icon of widget i want to show the context menu.

is there a way to do it ? i am using `android 2.3.X` and android support compatibility package too.

here is what i want

[image]

The widget that i have created is derived from `AppWidgetProvider` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no way to open a context menu when we click on widget.

But alternatively we can open an activity instead and make it transparent then open a dialog box which contains ListView in that way we can mimic the look of context menu.

That is how i eventually did in my application.